# SQL по запросу бОльшего числа выдает не то что ожидаешь

Tags: sql

Запрос на вывод наибольшего значения из БД

```
SELECT max(fa_total) as fa_total FROM fa WHERE user_id = $id;
```

К примеру в таблице fa содержится три строки. В столбце есть три ячейки со значениями:

36500
9985
1200

Ожидаю что запрос вернет бОлшее число т.е. 36500, а выводится 9985. Но увы.

Если в самой таблице в phpMyAdmin отсортировать строки по величине значения, то иерархия выглядит так:

9985
36500
1200

И конечно же вопрос, как стребовать наибольшее число в таком случае?

Comment: А у вас колонка fa_total в БД числовая ?

Comment: нет, там ВарЧар, так как самая первая строка содержит текст. Можно без INT сортировать числа?

Comment: строки сортируются в лексографическом порядке. Что бы сортировать числа вам надо привести строку к числу в любом случае. либо в БД, либо в самом запросе `sum(cast(fa_total as int))` например. Точные способы конвертации зависят от конкретной БД, везде разные. Правда после этого в некоторых БД запрос начнет с ошибкой падать, если вы строку не из цифр захотите сконвертить ...

Comment: Когда задаете вопрос, необходимо предоставить "Минимальный воспроизводимый пример".
Для справки: Как создать минимальный, самодостаточный и воспроизводимый пример
https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Для вашего сценария это означает следующее:
(1) DDL и образец вставки данных, т.е. CREATE table(s) плюс операторы INSERT, в SQL.
(2) Что вам нужно сделать, т.е. логика и ваш SQL код пытающийся ее реализовать.
(3) Ожидаемый результат на основе примера данных в #1 выше.
(4) Ваша база данных (СУБД) и ее версия.

Comment: Если СУБД MS SQL, можно использовать try_cast, тогда все текстовые значение будут конвертированы в NULL